# Создание автоматических массивов с неизвестной на этапе компиляции длиной

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Почему в С++ можно создать одномерный массив с заранее не известной длиной на стеке?

```
int size;
cin>>size;
int a[size];
```

И двумерный тоже создается:

```
int size;
cin>>size;
int a[size][size];
```

Однако при попытке записать туда что-то программа падает из-за Segmentation Fault. Пытался записать массив 2048*2048.На малых размерах массива все работает. При этом компилятор(g++) ни на что не ругался.
Разве размер не должен быть известен на этапе компиляции? Пытался создать динамический двумерный массив вот так

```
int **buffer = new int[s][s];
```

Однако компилятор начал ругаться:

> main.cpp:9:29: error: array size in new-expression must be constant

Размер же памяти, которую нужно выделить известен, в чем проблема?

Собственно, вопросы:

1) Можно ли создавать автоматические одно-, много- мерные массивы, с заранее не известными размерами?

2) Если компилятор не ругался на создание автоматического массива

```
int a[size][size];
```

то почему он ругается на создание такого же массива

```
int **buffer = new int[s][s];
```

но только в куче?

P.S. как правильно создавать динамические я знаю, просто мне нужен был двумерный динамический массив в котором элементы расположены в памяти так же, как и в автоматических массивах(элементы расположены построчно).

Comment: Ну это же известная фишка GCC, в стандарте такого нет.

Comment: Переползайте на STD::векторы: там можно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала — нет, массив переменного размера по стандарту создать на стеке нельзя. То, что у вас это компилируется — это расширение C++, существующее в gcc. Отключить расширения языка можно при помощи ключей `-pedantic -Werror`.

Ну и из смысла операции (выделение `2048 * 2048 * sizeof(int)` = 16Mб на стеке) — должно падать по переполнению стека.

---

Многомерный массив `int**` — это массив указателей на массивы. Соответственно и выделять его нужно по частям: сначала сам массив указателей, а потом каждый из подмассивов:

```
int **buffer = new int*[s];
for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
    buffer[i] = new int[s];
```

Если вы хотите массив типа `int[][]`, с этим сложнее. Вы можете всё ещё создать его, но для этого все размеры, кроме первого, должны быть известны на этапе компиляции!

```
int (*buffer)[10] = new int[s][10];
```

Почему так? Это для того, чтобы компилятор мог подсчитать, по какому же смещению от начала находится элемент `buffer[1][0]`. Иначе компилятор не сможет этого выяснить: для этого нужно знать размер строки массива (ведь `buffer[1][0]` расположено по смещению, равному размеру строки, от начала `buffer`!)

---

Большой обзор по теме (на английском): [*How do I use arrays in C++?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4810676/276994)

Comment: А в чем проблема вот тут: int **buffer = new int[s][s]; ?

Comment: @Asem: Как раз дописал.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так

```
int ** i = new int[n][n];
```

не создаются массивы, как бы вы этого не хотели. Да и тип выражения `int[n][n]` будет низведен до `int*`, но не `int**`.

```
int ** i = new int*[n];
for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) i[j] = new int[n];
```

Судите сами: `new` выделяет память одним куском. Ваше же `int**` уже предусматривает, что будет массив указателей, каждый из которых будет указывать на некоторую новую память. И кто, по-вашему, должен этим заниматься? :)

Если вы хотите провести аналогию с массивом

```
int i[N][N];
```

то тут `i` приводится к `int*`, ни никак не к `int**`, а при обращении к элементам массива компилятор, *зная во время компиляции* размеры, генерирует код, который обращается к нужному месту в памяти - и это отнюдь не разыменование `i[n]`...